# Can a java web start application exist without .jnlp file?

Tags: java, java-web-start

As explained in [Java Web Start](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start) it seems to have necessary to have a .jnlp file for a Java Web Start application. My application does not have a single .jnlp file . My application does not have `main()` as it has `run()` in almost every class. Could anyone please explain without main & JNLP file how a Web Start works?

Comment: I think you need both main() and .jnlp file. I dont understand how you are starting program without main? is it web application? or running in any container? if any answer is yes than why you need web start?

Comment: You do seem very confused.  Read the [JWS Tag Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) and see if JWS is what you actually need.

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson : Actually i am confused over as i came to know that my application is a JWS as it does not run in context of a browser. But at the same time it does not have any .jnlp file. Do you mean to say that my apllication has some xmlformat that is dealing for .jnlp file? Please explain....

Comment: You're confused all right. Not running in a browser context just means that it *isn't an applet*. It doesn't mean that it *is* a JWS application. The *presence of a .jnlp file* means it is a JWS application. What you have is an ordinary Java desktop application, or, if you really don't have a main() method, either an API or some kind of plugin.

Comment: Thanks EJP. Actually imy application neither have main() method nor .jnlp file. But it used jnlp as it says somwhere to run jnlp file like (somejavascript).returnpage=jnlp;   What does it conclude??

Comment: The Deployment descriptor which should be in the client code is found in the server code. Is this the indicatipon that the deployement descriptor is dowloaded from server after requesting url to the server?

Answer (score 2):

> Could anyone please explain without main() & .jnlp file how a web
>   start works?

It *doesn't* work without a .jnlp file. You have to provide a .jnlp file, and you also have to provide a main() method or an Applet class that it can start up.

Comment: As for now i conclude that that my application is jws but it generate jnlp format after receiving response from the server which is in written in c++.