# Can jnlp file be generated dynamically by the response from the server?

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a java web start application exist without .jnlp file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207945/can-a-java-web-start-application-exist-without-jnlp-file)

My application neither have a jnlp file nor main() method But it is a java web start application. Is there anything like when we start application by requesting http:\[ip address]:[port no] the jnlp file is generated and sent through the jar by xml? Could anyone please explian .... Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your reason for believing it's a JWS application?

Comment: @ ejp The reason behind believing my application is java web start is it runs in a sandbox, and the jar's are downloaded in client machine cache and application runs on the client machine.

Answer (score 3):

First, I do not understand how can your application run without `main()`. Application must have main method. To start application using JNLP you just have to perform HTTP request to URL that returns the JNLP descriptor that is XML file with mime type `application/x-java-jnlp-file`. So to create it dynamically you just have to create JSP or servlet that generates your descriptor and defines HTTP header

`Content-Type: application/x-java-jnlp-file`

Comment: Thanks a lot AlexR. Actually this is bugging me also that such a huge code does not have a main() but have public void run() in almost every .java file. You mean to say that a jws application can exist which does not have a .jnlp file but the deployment descriptor can be created through sevlet?